# Having POCOs, Entities and ViewModels in a solution feels like overkill

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The latest version of the Entity Framework got me in love, still at good as it is I don't like using entities objects as domain objects for all the obvious headaches, so what I'm doing is translating retrieved entity objects in my services and returning POCOs to whomever consumes the service. Thanks to automapper the translation from pocos to entities and back results in some easily maintainable code inside the services. Where things get hairy is when you add ViewModels to the picture and you end up mapping a viewmodel to the poco in the controller and then mapping the poco to the entity object in the service to be stored in the repository.

Would you consider this an overkill or am I being too nitpicking ?

Comment: Why can't AutoMapper solve view model mapping for you, too? You have to map, anyway; you can do this in view (very bad), in view model manually (not too bad), in isolated mapping classes (good, used in MVC In Action book), or using AutoMapper (once again separate code, very good). If you do this inside view, it doesn't mean there's no mapping; you just trade maintainability (putting it into separate place) for development speed.

Comment: Can't you use POCOs for entities now? I don't think you need any special Entity objects anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not 'overkill' but 'overhead'. And It is inevitable when you want proper layering. The ViewModels belong to the UI layer, you don't want to mix that with the POCOs.

And while you might call it 'overkill' for a small app, which boundary would you rather sacrifice?

Comment: +1 agreed - necessary initial overhead, but pays off over the app's lifetime, at least in an enterprise environment. Might be a bit different for a hobbyist or small business project...

Comment: Agreed, I'd rather keep the perceived overhead than having to pass a domain object and a horde of loose objects in the ViewData or having to use entity objects as domain objects.

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework 4 has built-in support for POCO's. A good place to start on that is [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/poco-in-the-entity-framework-4-part-1-the-experience)

In short, you can have your domain model project that is completely persistence ignorant. You can use this approach with the newly introduced Code First approach in EF 4. Now you don't need Automapper anymore for your POCO's to Entity Objects conversion and vice versa. You can, however, use Automapper to map between POCO's and ViewModels reducing a lot of the plumbing code.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a heap for the link, the approach you mention seems mighty interesting.